# How to use different scale for one tikz scope in two slides in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, xetex, pdftex, tikz-node

**Basic Info**

I use xelatex (even though the same things happen while using pdflatex) and TeX Live 2019 in an MBP.

**Original Problems**

I want to use different scales for the same tizk scope in different slides. To give an example, I want to combine the following two scopes into one while still keeping the functionality of changing the scale from slide 1 to 2. The real node is much more complicated than this, so I don't want to copy and paste.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \begin{scope}[scale=1,transform shape]
             \node<1> (test) at (current page) [circle,very thick, draw=black, fill=white, text width=0.3\textwidth, align=center, font=\huge\bfseries , inner sep=-1ex] {TEST};
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[scale=2,transform shape]
            \node<2> (test) at (current page) [circle,very thick, draw=black, fill=white, text width=0.3\textwidth, align=center, font=\huge\bfseries , inner sep=-1ex] {TEST};
       \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have tried the following strategy

```
\begin{scope}[\alt<1>{scale=1}{scale=2},transform shape]
    \node<1-2> ...
```

```
\begin{scope}[scale=\alt<1>{1}{2},transform shape]
    \node<1-2> ...
```

```
\begin{scope}\alt<1>{[scale=1,transform shape]}{[scale=2,transform shape]}
    \node<1-2> ...
```

But the first two give me some wrong messages and stop compiling and the last one simply doesn't work.

So, how to make this work?

**Extensions**

Actually, this question applies to nearly all the arguments of tikzpicture inside square brackets []. For example, what should I do if I want to change the font from `\huge` to `\normalsize` while the slide number change from 1 to 2?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You might find it useful to look at the tikz library `overlay-beamer-styles` which can be used to make tikz styles overlay-aware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using the TikZ library `overlay-beamer-styles` which defines a variety of useful keys, most relevant being:

```
alt=<overlay specification>{first styles}{second styles}
```

which applies the `first styles` when the overlay specification is met and the `second styles` when not.  In your code, this could look like:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/611127/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-2> % <- needed to force a second frame
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\begin{scope}[
  alt=<1>{scale=1}{scale=2}, % <- overlay-aware styles
  transform shape]
\node[
  alt=<1>{at=(current page)}{at=(current page.north)},
  circle,
  very thick,
  draw=black,
  fill=white,
  text width=0.3\textwidth,
  align=center,
  font=\huge\bfseries ,
  inner sep=-1ex
]
(test)  {TEST};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This only works for things set in keys, so to use it for positioning a node then you need to use the `at` key rather than the inline `at` syntax, as demonstrated above.

The `<1-2>` on the `\begin{frame}` is because and `\alt` by itself doesn't force a second overlay; if other material on the slide referred to more overlays then that wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thank you! This surely satisfy all my needs! But, a further question, does this trick also apply to the position specification? I tried something like ```alt=<1>{at (current page)}{at (current page.north)}``` and ```at alt=<1>{(current page)}{(current page.north)}``` but they both give error.

Comment: I take a look at the documentation of ```overlay-beamer-styles```, which I assume to be this: https://ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/aobs-tikz/aobs-tikz.pdf , but I find no useful information.

Comment: @QiTianluo To use it for positioning, you need to use the `at` _key_ rather than the `\node at (coordinate) ...` syntax.  Also, that is the correct documentation but this particular key isn't described there in the main part but in the code.  There are many examples of its use on this site.

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, by clicking on your profile, I find that Dr. Stacey you happen to be the author of one of my most commonly used package for tikz ```tikzmark```. So could you recommend me some introductory references for a previously LaTeX user like me to go deeper in the system and eventually maybe write some package. Actually I'm planning to write some package facilitating the positioning of object in beamer. It is really frustrating for now in the sense that one have to try many times before finding the proper and even perfect positioning if one has many objects in one frame.

Comment: To make a comparison, positioning of objects in the WYSIWYG application like Microsoft Powerpoint is relatively less that frustrating since one can just drag the object. I think it will be more efficient if one can realize similar, or fake similar functionality. For example, one may drag to know the more proper coordinate and then he can come back to the source code to use this coordinate.

Comment: @QiTianluo I think that there are some WYSIWYG programs for designing TikZ pictures, but I've never used one so I have no opinion on how good they are.  I find drag-to-position intensely frustrating for a variety of reasons that probably aren't worth expanding on and are more about what I'm used to than anything else.  For absolutely positioning in a beamer frame, I'd probably work with the `current page` node and the `calc` library to get things where I want, and if positioning relative to things already on the page then there's always `tikzmark` - that's what it was originally for!

Comment: Yes! ```current page```, ```calc``` and your ```tikzmark``` is exactly what I'm using for now. Still, it would be good if you could recommend me some references, or maybe introductory textbooks for beginners of the programming, but not just the use, of LaTeX. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @QiTianluo I don't know much of references.  I tend to use LaTeX3 for anything technical these days and `texdoc interface3` is my go-to reference for that.  The TikZ manual has quite a bit towards the end on lower-level programming with TikZ.  I also tend to ask a lot of questions here!

Comment: Understood! Thank you! BTW, I'm still under the impression that we are using LaTeX2e, and LaTeX3 is still under construction. So I'm wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128740/discussion-between-qi-tianluo-and-andrew-stacey).

Answer (score 4):

The syntax

```
\begin{scope}[<options>]
```

is basically just a shortcut for

```
\begin{scope}
  \tikzset{<options>}
```

so you can just use that together with `\alt`:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[transform shape]
      \alt<1>{%
        \tikzset{scale=1,my font/.style={font=\itshape\LARGE}}%
      }{%
        \tikzset{scale=2,my font/.style={font=\huge\bfseries}}%
      }
      \node<1-2> (test) at (current page) [circle,very thick, draw=black, fill=white, text width=0.3\textwidth, align=center, my font, inner sep=-1ex] {TEST};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Can this be used for the alternation of, for example the font style in the node?

Comment: @QiTianluo Sure, see the updated answer.

Comment: So, my impression is that this strategy is not applicable inside the square bracket since the ```\tikzset``` syntax is not applicable there. Don't know whether my understanding is correct?

Comment: @QiTianluo No, because content inside square brackets is never expanded before being read which means that TikZ sees literally the entire `\alt<1>{scale=1}{scale=2}` and tries to look that up as a key. Sometimes there is some `\expandafter` trickery that can be done, but not in this case because `\alt` is not fully expandable.